# How to send Riley out to Attack in Call of Duty:Ghosts multiplayer?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

How can you send Riley the Dog out to attack in Call of Duty: Ghosts Multiplayer? I've seen him attacking people but the description only reads something like

> Nothing like man's best friend watching your back.

Does this mean that he can only defend a given radius around the player or can you specifically tell him to go attack a given point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't order the guard dog to attack in multi-player.

The dog will follow you around and will attack enemies within a certain radius. Once the enemy is eliminated he will return to you. If you die, the dog will attempt to make it back to you and will defend it self along the way if necessary. The dog is also meant to growl or bark when an enemy is close.

My limited personal experience of this kill-streak is that the dog does not need line of sight to attack a player. If you come into its "attack" radius, then it will try and attack. I say try, because I've noticed on a few occasions that they can get stuck or confused as which is the best route to take for the kill!

The dog will happily jump out windows and off ledges if it thinks it can defend you. This doesn't seem to hurt it. A dog can take significantly more damage than a player can, but can be stunned for short periods of time by explosions, tactical grenades or heavy bullet damage.

If a dog comes across another dog they will attack each other, but won't kill. They will continue to fight until a player kills one of them.

Comment: I had heard some players asking and it was making me curious. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Riley will attack within a certain radius of your player he can follow you around and safe your life many times. If you die, it will track you to where you respawned and protect you and itself along the way sometimes. But unfortunately you can not order an attack on or in a special area.

Answer (score 0):

You can't order him anywhere but I find it effective if he has to cross the map to get back to you. So other than by death, if you are creative in the way that you spawn him (e.g., spawn him and the go up a ladder) you can sometimes get a few extra kills by running across the map.

Answer (score -5):

If you know where the enemy is and you're in close range but Riley still won't attack, you can sometimes aim at the enemy's position and Riley should then attack.